# Using hammer js with a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, multi-touch, hammer.js

I have a little problem using Hammer JS with my canvas.

I explain  ;

I have a canvas defined like this :

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

In this canvas, i add some Img :

```
var s = new CanvasState(document.getElementById('myCanvas');
s.addImg(new Img(100, 0, data.image, data.identifiant));
```

And , i would like to use Hammer JS to rotate my new Img.

For this, i tried something like :

```
var hammertime = new Hammer(document.getElementById('myCanvas'));
hammertime.on('pan', function(ev) {
            console.log(ev);
        });
hammertime.get('pinch').set({ enable: true });
hammertime.get('rotate').set({ enable: true });
```

I don't know what i should put instead myCanvas. I tried something like myCanvas.selection (the IMG OBJECT) but in vain ..

Any idea ? Any person who already used Hammer JS with a canvas on which we have elements / objects ?

Seems hammerJS don't recognized Objects ..

Thanks

Comment: What is `CanvasState`? Why is it even mentioned in the question? Does it work if you don't initialize `CanvasState`?

Comment: CanvasState is a function which give me current state of my Canvas, in this function i define all my events 'onclick' , 'mousedown' ...
I don't think it can work if i don't initialize it because i'm not able to refresh my canva is i add a new image. But i whould like to use HammerJS on the image added

Comment: `HammerJs` is going to recognize HTML elements, not bytes rendered inside a canvas... canvas is a bitmap, there are no objects that it knows about. How do you expect `HammerJS` to know about an abstraction from `CanvasState`? HammerJS is not going to rotate an image added with CanvasState, you can rotate the entire canvas....

Comment: Make sure you target the correct element in your page. This may help: For Fabric.js (a canvas library), you initiate Hammer.js like this: `var hammer = new Hammer(myFabricInstance.upperCanvasEl)`. The element `.upperCanvasEl` is auto-generated by Fabric JS and appears on top of the main drawing canvas, so this is likely capturing touch events.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Fabric.js library. It is canvas library, that helps you interact with it much easier. Point is - hammerjs in working very nicely with Fabric.js.

All you need to do, once you have inicialized Fabric.js is this:

```
const hammertime = new Hammer(canvas.upperCanvasEl);

hammertime.get('pinch').set({ enable: true });
hammertime.get('pan').set({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL });

hammertime.on('pan', (ev) => {
  alert("pan!");
});
```

Please note, if you want to enable pinch gesture, you need to enable it.

"canvas" is Fabric.js initialized canvas element.

"upperCanvasEl" is generated by Fabric.js and intercepts all events. Please note, if you use TypeScript that this property is not yet supported by it, so you need to cast it to "any".

Comment: Instead of directly accessing `upperCanvasEl` you can call the method `getSelectionElement()`. This is probably the proper and intended way to get the upper canvas in Fabric.js as this is a public method in the TypeScript types whereas `upperCanvasEl` is a private property as mentioned above.